# Spring Filter For URL Pattern with Path Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use filter for centain url in Spring.
When i use it like this:

```
registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/user/*");
```

It's work for all url that starts with "/api/user"

But when i use it like this:

```
registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/user/*/activate");
```

It didn't work for "/api/user/607a7244-3db9-429a-89f0-1662da0b0e15/activate"

I checked it on the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html),
they said:
`* matches zero or more characters`

Anyone know why "/api/user/*/activate" not match with "/api/user/607a7244-3db9-429a-89f0-1662da0b0e15/activate"?

Comment: It works for an `AntMatcher` but filters don't use an `AntMatcher` but how things are specified in the servlet specification. So only the first will work, the second won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to register a filter using the `FilterRegistrationBean`. As this is a `Filter` being registered the URL mapping relies on the support of the servlet container **not** the support in Spring (Boot).

URL mapping of the servlet container is determined by what is specified in [the servlet specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf) (See section 12.2). Which is also mentioned in [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/AbstractFilterRegistrationBean.html#addUrlPatterns-java.lang.String...-) of the `addUrlPatterns` method.

The URL mapping in the servlet specification is very basic and is only matching the first part of the URL. So that is why your first, `/api/user/*` works (as the URL starts with `/api/user` but not `/api/user/*/activate` because it doesn't start with `/api/user/*/activate`. It isn't ant-style expression just a simple pattern for the start of a URL.